# ADB keeps crashing after update 2022.3.1 patch 4. Ucrtbase.dll?

Tags: android-studio, windows-7, adb

After installing the latest update on both laptop (Win7) and desktop (Win7 Pro) I can't connect a physical device or start an emulator. Android Studio reports that the adb server can't start and keeps trying to restart it. Windows event log reports that adb.exe keeps crashing due to ucrtbase.dll.

I've tried reinstalling Visual C++ libraries for 2022 and reverting to Android Studio Electric Eel, but it keeps happening.

I also tried to run in admin mode as per another question posted here, but no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Windows 7 is no longer supported by Android SDK. We had multiple questions here on SO about failing Android SDK Tools on Win 7 in the last two or three weeks.

Comment: Was there an official announcement about this? I can see they've stopped support for 32bit, but I'm on 64.

Comment: The Android Studio Download says Windows (8, 10, or 11) and Google seems to consider Android SDK now as part of Android Studio. https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-install-android-studio#1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same for me. Adb from android platform tools 34.0.5 crashes on windows 7. Had to take previous version https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r34.0.4-windows.zip, unpack to path-to-sdk\platform-tools and it works now. Waiting for another solution.

Comment: This worked. Thanks very much. Is it a permanent thing like Robert mentioned above, or will an update fix it? I'm wondering if it's worth filing a ticket.

Comment: I don't know. Maybe it's worth filing a ticket to get a clear official answer.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio requires Windows 8 or later (https://developer.android.com/studio/install).

If you can reproduce crashes on any supported version of Windows, please file a public bug at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192795 and we shall engage directly.